# Connection refused to target machine using WPF window application in C#?

Tags: c#, json, wpf, tcpclient, tcpserver

I need some help in two forms, one form i have TCPClient that needs to send a request to TCpServer. TCPServer must be able to pick up the new request as data(json).

Second one, TCPClient which is one seperate window does not communicate with TCPServer. Therefore i am now getting connection refuse to target machine and there is no issue related to firewall or ports. When i debug my code as an initial step it gets refused from this line
await using NetworkStream stream = Client.GetStream();

I am using two testing tool for this window application
-putty to telnet using IP address 127.0.0.1 and port to listen 12345(Network:connection refused)
-echotool.exe

```
//TCPClient and XAML code

//Back end

<pre>using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;


namespace PingServerApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

           
        }

        // declaring some local variables and method for clicking buttons.

        bool eco = false;
        async void OnClick1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // add to datagrid
            dataGrid.Items.Clear();
            await TcpRequest();
        }

       

        void OnClick2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            eco = false;
        }
        class Body { public Guid Id { get; set; } }

        // class for model

        public class TCPConnectionModel
        {
            public TimeOnly Started { get; set; }
            public TimeOnly Processed { get; set; }
            public TimeSpan Elapsed { get { return Processed - Started; } set { } }
        }

        // TCPRequest for body and serialize and deserialize json data

        async Task TcpRequest()
        {
            try
            {

                // initiate tcp
                IPHostEntry IpHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1");
                IPAddress IpAddress = IpHostInfo.AddressList[0];

                // initiate endPoint
                var endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IpAddress, 12345);

                // starting tcp client
                using TcpClient Client = new TcpClient();
                await Client.ConnectAsync(endPoint);
                await using NetworkStream stream = Client.GetStream();
                eco = true;
                while (eco)
                {

                    // start timer
                    TCPConnectionModel displayData = new() { Started = TimeOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now) };

                    // initiate send data
                    Body requestBody = new() { Id = Guid.NewGuid() };

                    //initiate recieve data
                    var buffer = new byte[1_024];

                    // Json Serialize
                    string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(requestBody);

                    // tcp send
                    await stream.WriteAsync(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonString));

                    // tcp recieve and decode
                    int received = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer);
                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, received);

                    // json Deserialize
                    Body? recievedBody = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Body>(message);

                    // stop timer
                    displayData.Processed = TimeOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);

                    // delay for 500ms
                    Thread.Sleep(500);

                    // add to datagrid
                    dataGrid.Items.Add(displayData);

                    // display result in status bar
                    resultveiw.Text = message;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                resultveiw.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}

<Window x:Class="PingServerApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PingServerApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="btn1" Content="Start" Click="OnClick1" ClickMode="Press" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="418,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.517,0.658" Height="55" Width="385" Background="Gold"/>
        <Button Name="btn2" Content="Stop" Click="OnClick2" ClickMode="Press" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="418,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="390" Height="55" Background="Aqua"/>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding TCPConnectionModel}" Margin="0,0,387,10">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header = "Started" Binding = "{Binding Started}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header = "Processed" Binding = "{Binding Processed}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header = "Elapsed?" Binding = "{Binding Elapsed}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <StatusBar Margin="413,293,5,10">
            <StatusBarItem Width="380" Height="69" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" RenderTransformOrigin="0.486,0.619" Margin="0,0,0,21">
                <TextBlock Text="Nothing yet" x:Name="resultveiw"></TextBlock>
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>
    </Grid>
</Window>



//TCPServer and XAML
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using SimpleTCP;
using System.IO;

namespace GUI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for EchoWindowTest.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class EchoWindowTest : Window
    {
        public EchoWindowTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        SimpleTcpServer server;


        public class DisplayData
        {
            public TimeOnly Started { get; set; }
            public TimeOnly Processed { get; set; }
            public TimeSpan Elapsed { get { return Processed - Started; } set { } }
        }
        private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                DisplayData displayData = new() { Started = TimeOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now) };
                displayData.Processed = TimeOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
                server = new SimpleTcpServer();
                server.Delimiter = 0 * 13;
                server.StringEncoder = Encoding.UTF8;
                server.DataReceived += Server_DataReceived;




                Thread.Sleep(500);
                dataGrid.Items.Add(displayData);



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                txtStatus.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
        private void Server_DataReceived(object sender, SimpleTCP.Message e)
        {
            txtStatus.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(delegate
            {
                txtStatus.Text += e.MessageString;

            }));
        }

        public void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) /*Start button*/
        {
            txtStatus.Text += "Server starting ...";
            System.Net.IPAddress ip = new System.Net.IPAddress(long.Parse(txtHost.Text));
            server.Start(ip, Convert.ToInt32(txtPort.Text));



        }

        public void btnStop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) /*Stop button*/
        {
            if (server.IsStarted)
                server.Stop();

        }



    }
}
<Window x:Class="GUI.EchoWindowTest"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GUI"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="EchoWindowTest" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>

        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF39494C" Offset="0.008"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF39494C" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Label Content="Host:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="204,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="62" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"/>
        <Label Content="Port:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="366,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="40" Width="56" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"/>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding displayDataList}" Margin="0,0,617,0" Background="#FFDDDDDD">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header = "Started" Binding = "{Binding Started}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header = "Processed" Binding = "{Binding Processed}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header = "Elapsed?" Binding = "{Binding Elapsed}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button x:Name="btnStart" Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="524,97,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="97" Click="btnStart_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnStop" Content="Stop" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="651,97,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="95" Click="btnStop_Click"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtStatus" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="159" Margin="204,169,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="542" Background="#FFDDDDDD"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtHost" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="262,100,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="127.0.0.1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" FontSize="20" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtPort" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="418,99,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="12345" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" FontSize="20" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="White"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: IPAddress IpAddress = IpHostInfo.AddressList[0]; index zero is IPV6.  Try index one.

Comment: @jdweg still no changes still getting the same connection to target machine, is it possible to use my code on your VS and download echotool.exe as well putty to test my code. surely you will get the same on your end.

Comment: You can only have one connection with the same three properties 1) Source IP address 2) Destination IP address 3) Port number.  When your client and server are one the same machine the client and server cannot be the same.  So you normally make the server listen to the loopback 127.0.0.1.  Than make client connect to the IP of the machine.  So the server has to start before client.  The client cannot use the loopback to connect and must use the IP address of the machine.  I've seen the refuse message occur when client tries to connect to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @jdweg i seem to get your point and you right.maybe i need your help. to show me from the given code. where to change from which line? I will make the amendments and update you

Comment: In client change following to either the computer name or IP : IPHostEntry IpHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1");

Comment: @jdweng by changing these, i should be able to get the response back than connection refused target machine?

Comment: The connection will complete.  A response will not occur until data is sent.  Normally you have a master/slave with client being the master and server the slave.  Client sends a message and server responds.

Comment: @jdweg now u raising an import point, how do i ran these two windows application? Must i both open them together, then i start with server and while server runs i test using putty, then bring up the client?

Comment: The listener must start before the client.  There is a difference between a Chat application and an automated application.   The chat the human brain is the controller, while an automated application the software has to be the controller.  With a chat application the brain waits for a message to complete and joins the messages.  Automated you have to write software to do what the brain does.